# time complexity of randomized array insertion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, insert, time-complexity

So I had to insert N elements in random order into a size-N array, but I am not sure about the time complexity of the program

the program is basically:

```
for (i = 0 -> n-1){
    index = random (0, n); (n is exclusive)
    while (array[index] != null)
         index = random (0, n);
    array[index] = n
 }
```

Here is my assumption: a normal insertion of N numbers is of course strictly N, but how much cost will the collision from random positions cost? For each n, its collision rate increases like 0, 1/n, 2/n .... n-1/n,  so expected number of insertions attempts will be 1, 2, 3 .. n-1, this is O(n), so total time complexity will be O(n^2), so is this the average cost? but wow this is really bad, am I right?

So what will happen if I do a linear search instead of keep trying to generate random numbers? Its worst case will obviously be O(n^2>, but I don't know how to analyze its average case, which depends on average input distribution?

Comment: the fourth line should read `array[index] = i` I guess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the inner loop. When do we expect to have our first success (find an open position) when there are `i` values already in the array? For this we use the [*geometric distribution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):

`Pr(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p`

Where `p` is the probability of success for an attempt.
Here `p` is the probability that the array index is not already filled.
There are `i` filled positions so `p = (1 - (i/n)) = ((n - i)/n)`.

From the wiki, the expectation for the geometric distribution is `1/p = 1 / ((n-i)/n) = n/(n-i)`.
Therefore, we should expect to make `(n / (n - i))` attempts in the inner loop when there are `i` items in the array.

To fill the array, we insert a new value when the array has `i=0..n-1` items in it. The amount of attempts we expect to make overall is the sum:

```
sum_{i=0,n-1} n/(n-i)
= n * sum_{i=0,n-1}(1/(n-i))
= n * sum_{i=0,n-1}(1/(n-i))
= n * (1/n + 1/(n-1) + ... + 1/1)
= n * (1/1 + ... + 1/(n-1) + 1/n)
= n * sum_{i=1,n}(1/i)
```

Which is `n` times the [*nth harmonic number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and is approximately `ln(n) + gamma`, where gamma is a constant. So overall, the number of attempts is approximately `n * (ln(n) + gamma)`, which is `O(nlog n)`. Remember that this is only the expectation and there is no true upper bound since the inner loop is random; it may never find an open spot.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of insertions attempt at step i is

```
sum_{t=0}^infinity (1-i/n)^t * (n-i)/n * t 
= (n-i)/n * i/n * (1-i/n)^{-2}
= i/(n-i)
```

Summing over `i` you get

```
sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i/(n-1)
>= sum_{i=n/2}^n i / (n-i) 
>= n/2 sum_{x=1}^n/2 1/x
>= n/2 * log(n) + O(n)
```

And

```
sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i/(n-i)
<= n * sum _{x=1}^n 1/x
<= n * log(n) + O(n)
```

So you get exactly `n*log(n)` as an asymptotic complexity. Which is not as bad as you feared.

About doing a linear search, I don't know how you would do it while keeping the array random. If you really want an efficient algorithm to shuffle your array, you should check out Fisher-Yates shuffle.